# Best reporting engine for WPF without a database?

Tags: .net, wpf, xml, reporting

Does anyone know of a Reporting Engine for WPF? Most of the ones I could find are still for WinForms.

I'm happy enough using a WinForms one in WPF with a WinForms host so long as the tool has a UserControl that can be embedded in a window.

Also, I'm not using a database and all my data is in XML so the Reporting Engine needs to be able to handle that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've ended up going with [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx), but as a WinForms solution embedded in WPF. There are no WPF report viewers that can handle non-database report sources as of Jan 2009.

There seems to be a hole in the marketplace.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you can do the reporting in a FixedDocument of FlowDocument? I had the same issue, and in my situation (printing of a 1 page invoice), using a FixedDocument was an elegant and easy solution... (and inexpensive since i didn't need to buy a 3rd party reporting suite...)

Answer (score 2):

Here where I work, we use [Stimulsoft Reports.Net](http://www.stimulsoft.com/).  It can bind to a lot of things (including XML), and it can export to XPS, which you can then show in WPF using a [DocumentViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.documentviewer.aspx), or, if you're ambitious, you can rip open the XPS document using the XPS API, take the Glyphs and Paths out of every FixedPage, throw them on a Canvas, and display it in your app.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source [.NET Reporting Engine for WPF](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/). 
It supports headers and footers, DataTable binding, barcode generation and XPS creation. Not sure about XML binding though.

Answer (score 1):

ComponentOne Reports can handle non database report sources and it is WPF based. I tried it, and it seems quite decent

Answer (score 0):

also the following report engine could be useful too.
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/22ac97f3-4a3d-4fee-a411-e456f77f6a90/wpf-report-engine-part-3.aspx

Comment: Dear Manda, Welcome to SO. Try to include more information on your answer. In case the link is dead, your answer would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

I have released this, its open source and just takes any usercontrol you can create in WPF so its pretty flexible.

https://wpfreportingengine.codeplex.com/